# Наличие речевых ошибок, повтор местоимения

Tags: местоимение

Помогите, пожалуйста, определить, есть ли речевые ошибки в отрывке песни:

И грустны его глаза.
И остры его слова,
Жаль их царь совсем не слышит:

Всё смеётся от души,
Оценивая их в гроши.

Сомнения возникают следующие: Можно ли повторять два раза "их", не похоже ли это на тавтологию?

P.S. Ритм нарушен на словах ОЦЕНИВАЯ, ОНА и ИСПОЛНИЛ (см. текст песни) специально. Если слегка протянуть первый слог, когда поёшь под гитару, в этих словах, то получается довольно интересно. Меня волнует только "их": можно ли использовать повтор или нет?

Вот полный текст песни:

Эта роль ему мала. \
Сильно сгорблена спина, \
Будто кто-то давит свыше. \

И грустны его глаза. \
И остры его слова, \
Жаль их царь совсем не слышит: \

Все смеётся от души, \
Оценивая их в гроши. \

Припев: К издевкам шут давно привык. \
Никогда с ним не считались. \
Что ни говорил, у виска крутили иль смеялись. \
Но шут делал своё дело. \
По ночам он редко спал. \
Шел уверенно и смело, \
Цель свою ведь твердо знал. \

Армия готова в ночь \
Трон шуту занять помочь. \
Свергнут государя скоро. \

Освещает путь луна. \
И она здесь за шута. \
Дарит бледный свет безмолвно. \

Знает думы все его. \
Она их слушает давно. \

Припев: К издевкам шут давно привык. \
Никогда с ним не считались. \
Что ни говорил, у виска крутили иль смеялись. \
Но шут делал свое дело. \
По ночам он редко спал. \
Шел уверенно и смело, \
Цель свою ведь твердо знал. \

"Что ж не верил ты в меня, \
Мне не нравилась стезя, \
Та что выпала мне в жизни," - \

Шут корону в руки взял, \
Горб его совсем пропал. \
Государя стал шут выше. \

Протянул колпак царю, \
Исполнил шут свою мечту. \

Припев: И пляшет государь теперь \
В колпаке да с бубенцами, \
И кому не лень называют бранными словами. \
Бывший шут однако славен: \
Не глумится он над ним. \
Ведает, что всё же равен, \
Знает, что не важен грим. \

Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: Как бы вы изменили эти *стихи*, чтобы они по-прежнему *имели ритм*, но без повтора "их"?  Если предположить, что первое "их" относится к глазам, смысл-то у предложения будет?

Answer (score 1):

В предлагаемых стихах ритмика неверная, возможный вариант:

**"И грустны его глаза. И остры его слова, Жаль их царь совсем не слышит:
Всё смеётся от души, ценит в мелкие гроши".**

Имеется в виду: ценит слова в мелкие гроши.

ЦЕНИТЬ,  нсв. кого-что.  Разг. Назначать, определять цену кому-, чему-л.; оценивать. Во что ты ценишь эту картину?

Comment: Повтор местоимения в стихотворном тексте выглядит нормально, тем более местоимения расположены на расстоянии. Если бы мы взяли  обычный текст: " Царь их совсем не слышит, оценивает их в гроши",то повтор был бы стилистической неточностью.

Answer (score 0):

Ритм нарушен на слове **Оценивая**, и это надо править не только по рифме, но и смыслу.  **Их не слышит** не может относится **к глазам**, об этом говорит Victor Bazarov.